# Byte testing between user specified boundaries

Tags: c

I'm playing around attempting to check specific bytes within a packet's payload and test if they are >,<,!, = to a specified value.  The boundary points are dynamic, what is the best way to evaluate the bytes between them?

For example, I have a packet with a payload (following the headers of course) and I want to evaluate between byte 5 and byte 10 to see if it is greater than some specified value.

Comment: So you're dealing with a "packet". Is that in an array? A string? When you want to evaluate bytes 5 through 10 how do you intend to deal with bytes 6, 7, 8, and 9? Can you provide an example of an input array and what the expected result may be?

Comment: A packet is of course an array of bytes in a sense.  I don't know how to evaluate the in-between bytes, but perhaps I push them to a new chunk of memory and find their value? Preferably something like Snort's byte test

Comment: Q1 does "between byte 5 and byte 10" mean byte 5, bytes 6, ... bytes 10 or byte 6, bytes 7, ... bytes 9?  Q2: Is the range of bytes from first to last unbounded or limited to say 8?  Q3: Are the bytes to be arithmetically compared with a reference signed or unsigned or both, 2's compliment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `memcmp()` does a nice unsigned little endian compare.

return memcmp(&packet[IndexLo], &Reference, IndexHi - IndexLo + 1);

---

A portable method would simple compare 1 byte at a time.

---

Quick method but has a number of assumptions:
. Packet data and platform same endian and Little.
. `Boundary_width <= sizeof inttype`.
. unsigned arithmetic.
. Optimized for `Packet_CompareMask()`.
. Accessing a width integer on any byte boundary OK.
. OK to access memory just past end of `packet`.

```
typedef uint64_t inttype;

int Packet_CompareMask(const char *packet, size_t IndexLo, unint64_t Mask, inttype Reference) {
   // This fails on machine with alignment restricts on wide integers.
   inttype x = *((inttype *) &packet[IndexLo]);
   x &= Mask;
   if (x < Reference) return -1;
   return x > 0;
}

int Packet_CompareRange(const void *packet, size_t IndexLo, size_t IndexHi, inttype Reference) {
  inttype Mask = 0;
  ssize_t Diff = IndexHi - IndexLo;
  if ((Diff <= 0) || (Diff > (sizeof(Mask) - 1))) {
    ; // handle error
  }
  // This only works on little endian machines.  A variant would work with Big endian.
  while (--Diff >= 0) {
    Mask <<= 8;
    Mask |= 0xFF;
    }
  return Packet_CompareRange(packet, IndexLo, Mask, Reference);
}
```